# Origin of the use of "G-d"

Tags: words, language, writing-printing, etymology, divine-names

I'm wondering about the earliest uses of the abbreviation "G-d". Obviously, it's used as an extension to avoiding saying Hashem's name in vain, but was this practice common from the beginning as Jews started writing in English rather than just Hebrew or Yiddish? Also, is this practice used by Jews now writing in other languages like French or Spanish?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/112144/17072).

Comment: I cannot give you the earliest citation in English, but I can assure you that observant Jews writing in modern Spanish write "Di-s" (interestingly, the Judeo-Spanish equivelant is "Dió") and in modern French,"Di-u" is commonly employed

Comment: In French it's "D.ieu".